How much are muscle wear/tear obstacles to powered exoskeletons?
My world's setting is just a little bit into the future. The main change is that power generation is a lot more space/weight/economics-efficient, which has allowed for worn, powered exoskeletons with microcomputers in industrial, military, and police settings. There is nothing like biologically-embedded cybernetics or mastery over genetics, so without them, the exoskeletons are limited by that lowest common denominator.
Could that make using exoskeletons for running faster (e.g. a police chase on-foot) implausible?  If an exoskeleton moved an untrained human's legs as fast as Usain Bolt's, would this induce dangerous muscle strain and/or make the wearer feel fatigued? Or would this feel like a leisurely activity? There was a research paper in the Journal of Applied Physiology that concluded trained athletes would be capable of running up to 16.1 m/s (36 mph) if muscle reaction speed was fast enough, so it seems like there's plenty of wiggle room with how much human muscles can be strained by the exoskeletons, but that's also measured on trained athletes. It's unclear if an untrained, average person would experience muscle strain, or if they'd need to train up their muscles to be able to handle the strain.
There's also the factor of cold starting/stopping. Even normal workouts can leave muscles fatigued without a warm up/cool down, but is that a factor of human-powering the muscle, or the inherent movement? If an exoskeleton is powering the movement, would a lack of a warm-up still lead to straining the muscles?

Please edit the question to explain how the vehicles are supposed to be used, because otherwise it is very hard to say whether their use would be a strain or not. For example, I have a nice Wolkswagen Passat exoskeleton which can go much faster than 60 km/h and the activity does not strain my muscles at all. P.S. That journal is the Journal of Applied Physiology, not Psychology.

The VA has determined your injuries are not service related.

I foresee two things...
First, it's unreasonable to believe that your exoskeletons would be designed without keep-the-human-from-getting-hurt technology. Stuff like this could be modified, even overridden, but it would exist out-of-the-box if only to avoid legal liability.
Look at it this way: I damaged a knee as a teenager and now need a brace when I play sports. The brace I use has screws designed to limit both how far the brace will allow the knee to fold and how far it can straighten/extend. When I was younger and more athletic, those screws were set at a fairly wide angle. Today... Yeah... not so much.
Your exoskeletons would most definitely have these kinds of protections. Otherwise you get that humorous scene from Iron Man 2 when Tony's showing the failures of other manufacturers to build powered armor.
Second, exoskeletons aren't magic. They're more than capable of enhancing strength, but it's a tough sell for me that they can in any way enhance reaction speed. Enhancing reaction speed is where you'd seriously damage the human because, even with training, the body is designed to try and stop an action it doesn't think it can control (think, "ow").
Consequently, the idea that an exoskeleton could help you run faster is unbelievable to me. At that point it's the exoskeleton that's in control, not the occupant. Even the decision to turn can't be the occupant's as it depends on how quickly they can react to an environment they can't process fast enough. Could you hand-wave this? Sure! But if you're looking for "realistic" (I'm not a fan because of exactly these kinds of issues... no imagination) then you need to avoid any enhancement that depends on the occupant's ability to "keep up."
If you're willing to do some hand-waving...
If you're willing to ignore the fine details, I believe it's reasonable to create a user interface that allows the occupant to invoke, for lack of a better term, Combo Moves. Short bursts of complex motion for which the occupant gives control entirely to the suit. The longer the "combo move," the less believable this solution.
But, in short, you can wear a body out
As a final note: even if the occupant were trained to completely relax and let go of control of the body (theoretically allowing for high speed running), you're still using joints, stretching and contracting ligaments, beating up cartilage, etc. Not only can I easily believe joint problems at young ages if said running were done frequently, I can imagine spine problems and even cardiovascular problems.
And that's ignoring the serious bruising the body would get as it's thrown against the suit's restraints during all those high-speed maneuvers. Stop too quickly and you get whiplash, knock yourself out or even kill yourself. There's no physical difference between jumping off a roof and a quick enough stop from a high enough velocity.
Enhanced strength is a slow and controlled process — like using a forklift. The body isn't asked to actually do anything beyond what it's designed or trained to do. But running beyond the speed of the body's training (and the high-speed acrobatics needed for a good chase) would beat the snot out of the body.
And that brings us to the biggest problem when trying to make realistic unrealistic solutions
Curiously, I get to reference Iron Man 2 twice! When the primary antagonist is criticized for not making Iron Man suits that hold an occupant, he responds, "drone is better...."
A drone actually is better. So long as the communication interface is fast enough and secure enough, the drone can react in ways a human body can't in any circumstance. The funny thing is, when you free the brain from having to actually control the body, it can handle most of this. Said another way, it's easy to learn to pilot a supersonic jet when you're flying a simulator and not actually at the controls.
Consequently, it's really hard to believe your exoskeletons could chase down a Lamborghini. But it's easy to believe that the enforcement officer would pop a drone off the suit to out fly that lambo and disable it.
When it comes to dealing with circumstances requiring a faster reaction time... drone is better.

"The funny thing is, when you free the brain from having to actually control the body ..." - to paraphrase Star Wars: The Mandalorian, at a certain point, the weakest link for the power armor user eventually becomes the person inside the armor. +1

worth noting existing powered exoskeletons have limiters, mostly software based because if the exoskeltons can lift a ton, it can easily rip the tedons from your joints.

In rocket science there is this horrific thing called the Tsiolkovsky Rocket Equation and unfortunately it applies in some way to all the thing and the things it brings.
Muscle wear and tear occurs when the power-armour is not perfect — as in physical invisible. A perfect power-armour does not feel like one, its a thin layer of silk sheets you can feel the wind upon, as the circuitry within makes the mountain of metal sway just against the hairs on your skin.
Which gets us to what wears you down: imperfections in the mountain of metal.
Software: Todays control software usually uses some version of a derivative controller and if it goes wrong it gets into a cycle going of strange back and forth. And things go wrong all the time if you leave the usual envelope, which a power amour usually does. Humans do hyper-dexterity things (like plucking a flower) and hyper violent things (shoving a guy through the wall with a amour of power in the mouth still that flower). For one you need to tone it down, for the other amp it up, all while giving feedback, but not to much feedback else wear and tear on the muscles. Its a mountain of a task, as you need a scenario based predictator to adjust values and abstract away forces. Imagine you get punched or shoved... you fly into the back of your amour, which software without a clue, could easily interpret as a "he wants to go back — full steam!", flying you into a bathroom wall, which sends the opposite message through your body and into the brain of the amour — he wants to go forth. Built a heavy steel room, with a sloped floor and the old Mark 1 would punch its Users into pulp, while turning the safe into a sphere.... For all this, you need fast realtime computation, sensors (always on, always hackable) and frankly almost an AI to interpret the situation.
Hardware: Your mountain of steel needs actuators. Which have to be capable of lowforce and highforce, with the ability to holdback beyond a certain force. We have that, but its expensive: A normal industrial robot costs 30–40000€. A robot able to regulate the forces costs you 120,000€.
You can build all that in the shape of a suit and it will start to feel controllable — but then you brought your worst nemesis....
Physics: You brought a mountain of metal with you. And while the AI in it tries to keep it neutral, things can and will go wrong. First, you sink through way to many floors. And as the AI tries to keep it force neutral, you might not even feel it — just a silk sheet in the wind pressing against your chest, informing you that the bathroom floor gave way once more.

All that hardware needs all those batteries, which are bulky and weighty and

all that hardware needs all those batteries, which are bulky and weighty and

all that hardware needs all those batteries, which are bulky and weighty ...

the tyranny of the rocket equation begins to bite.


So lets go to the egineering department. They have all these funny posters on the wall and sad eyes when we break through the door frame in our power amour — again.
We can trade off power, we can trade off protection, we can trade off all the things.
But this is his heroic moment: the police doctor jumps through the window a chart of what the human body endures, when it receives more load — the result is obvious.
We have to cancel the power amour project and rely on purely robotic proxies, which do not have to carry around a fridge with a steak inside (that better be fresh when it comes back). Shape unconstrained we can go all in and make it fly, give it special appendages we can exchange depending on the task, make it look friendly ... the engineers are happy, the doctor is happy, the department is happy — the only downside is, we spend to much time in VR steering the proxy — and gain some weight.

Just design your exoskeletons properly. You can beat a man on foot by just making your strides longer. You don't have to move your legs any faster to cover more ground.
The idea has been around forever, folklore in multiple cultures has fancy shoes that chew through the miles. 7 League boots is one, but I vaguely recall some winged sandals and suchlike as well.
Either by mechanically enhanced powering off the step to go further or having longer legs on your exoskeleton.
In terms of reaction speed being faster and running like Bolt. Na, that wouldn't work out and there's no need for it anyway.

If you aren't using your muscles you won't be strained.
Here is a simple experiment, put your right arm in front of you and wave it rapidly from left to right pivoting from your elbow (not moving your shoulder). You will feel your muscles in your right arm doing work.
Now grab your right hand with your left hand and with your left hand and use that to move while you keep your right hand slack. Now you will only feel muscles in your left arm doing work while the right arm is relaxed.
If your exo-skeleton is doing all the work for moving your legs for you then you won't feel any strain. What would be painful is if the exo-skelton starts stretching your body past your flexibility, but you could do rapid number of short strides instead of going full olympic athlete stride length.
Human muscles can twitch pretty quickly, if exo-skeleton is doing most of the work then it would not be strenous to move quickly in a foot chase.
